# Consume SOAP Web-service in Play 1.x framework

Tags: java, web-services, soap, playframework

I just want to know is there any way to consume a SOAP web-service inside Play framework specifically version 1.x.x

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers are of course valid, but Play comes with a few handy classes for this kind of stuff. You will need to parse the response by hand though.
Start with the `WS` class. It can be used to post/get or whatever with all kinds of services. I use it for SOAP requests and REST calls for instance.

Example:

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
String username = "";
String password = "";
String url = "";
String postBody = "";

try {
    httpResponse = WS.url(url)
        .authenticate(username, password)
        .setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=UTF-8")
        .setHeader("SOAPAction", "")
        .body(postBody).post();

    Document document = httpResponse.getXml();
    String value = XPath.selectText("//value", document);
    Node node = XPath.selectNode("//node", document);

    // Do things with the nodes, value and so on

} catch (Exception e) {
    Logger.error("Do something with the connection error: %s", e);
}
```

As you can see, I use the `XPath` class to parse the returned `Document`. It offers all kinds of useful methods to traverse the Document.

Answer (score 1):

Using play as a SOAP consumer should be straightforward: include the soap library of your choice, generate the stubs from the wsdl, call the endpoint. Another option is to call the URL and use Xpath to parse its envelope.

Comment: Thanks, is there any limitation? And if is there any documented standard (based on play team) way to do it? Or I just follow the way I used to do outside of the play.

Comment: Use the SOAP client toolkit of your choice. Read questions posted on google group to know more : https://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/search?group=play-framework&q=soap