# how to consume SOAP ws from java play framework

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

In my search I found `Sbt Wsdl` liberty but i didn't find any good examples.

My second found was to use `WS` class of play but how do I pass it the `wsdl` file?

I need to parse on my own its return XML object.
[link to my second options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653821/consume-soap-web-service-in-play-1-x-framework)

What is the recommended way to handle soap from Play framework?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need to generate a WSDL client code that consists mainly of interfaces and annotated Java beans. Java offers `wsimport` for this routine, which requires just a URL to a proper WSDL schema (or already downloaded one and saved to a file).

Once generated, you can use it as a dependency in your business logic. However, that is quite cumbersome as it'd usually require you committing this code to the VCS which is a bit messy since the WSDL client is completely a boilerplate stuff with no logic in it.

There's an in-between option where you can auto-generate code every time you need it. I made a template project for Scala & SBT (I suppose you're using this as well) to save time on this: https://github.com/sainnr/sbt-scala-wsdl-template. Feel free to clone or fork it, hope it help someone a little bit.